# MySQL fulltext with score by columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search, match-against

I created an index like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `blog_posts`
ADD FULLTEXT `title_description_content` (`title`, `description`, `content`);
```

I can search with:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `blog_posts`
WHERE MATCH(title, content, description)
AGAINST("lorem ipsum" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
LIMIT 12
```

But I want to score by column. For example, that the title column is worth 3 points, that the description is worth 2 and the content is worth 1. So that words found in the title have a higher score.

I know this is possible because I already did it once, but I lost the source and I couldn't find any example on Google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple indexes for your problem

```
SELECT *,
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ("lorem ipsum" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS rel1,
  MATCH (content) AGAINST ("lorem ipsum" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS rel2,
  MATCH (description) AGAINST ("lorem ipsum" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS rel3
FROM `blog_posts`
WHERE MATCH(title, content, description) AGAINST("lorem ipsum" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY (rel1 * 3)+(rel2 * 2)+(rel3 * 1) DESC
LIMIT 12
```

The weight multiplications can be finetuned

Comment: I think that will require 4 FULLTEXT indexes -- one for each column plus one for the combination of 3 columns.  (At least in InnoDB.)

Comment: @RickJames that is correct, it is possible to skip the 4th in the where clause, because res1+res2+res3 has be bigger than 0, but that could give not the wanted results.